A lot of problems with modules for Python
How did that happen?
Many miss names and modules.
pip install pykaldi
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

sudo apt-get install python3-xyz
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-xyz


After 23.04, Ubuntu shows this error when you run Python command normally. You might need to use a venv to run your Python command. You can create one using the command python -m venv . and then activate is using source bin/activate

Also, I think this will answer your question in detail: pip error on Ubuntu: externally-managed-environment × This environment is externally managed

This question is similar to: pip error on Ubuntu: externally-managed-environment × This environment is externally managed. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

pip3 install --break-system-packages pykaldi
this will solve the problem

How and why and how do I find more info on this. Suggesting to install a package without any explanation is something that no one should ever do. How do I know this wont cause any problems? Please edit this answer and add some details.
